# How can we get the min date, per year and per ID, from data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have this data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-12-01', 'Year':'2020', 'ID':'123', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2019-02-01', 'Year':'2019', 'ID':'123', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2018-01-01', 'Year':'2018', 'ID':'234', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Library'}, 
       {'Month': '2021-04-01', 'Year':'2021', 'ID':'234', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Library'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Year':'2020', 'ID':'789', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2019-02-01', 'Year':'2019', 'ID':'789', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2018-12-01', 'Year':'2018', 'ID':'789', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2017-10-01', 'Year':'2017', 'ID':'123', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I thought the solution would look something like this code below, but this doesn't filter anything.

```
df_new = df[df.groupby(['ID','Year']).Month.transform('min') == df['Month']]
df_new
```

The final data frame should look like this.

```
2017-10-01  2017  123     1000     5000  Stadium
2018-01-01  2018  234     7000     5000  Library
2018-12-01  2018  789     5000     9000   Casino
```

Comment: "Month" contains already the year, so the desired output can be had with `df[df.groupby("ID").Month.transform("min") == df["Month"]]` Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm getting zero records returned when I try that. Does 'Month' have to be a specific data type?

Comment: Is "Month" a string `2019-02-01` as you have in question or `datetime` type?

Comment: It's a string. If I convert it to datetime, and run the code, I get this error.

ValueError: Lengths must match

Comment: Hmm, strange. When I run `df[df.groupby("ID").Month.transform("min") == df["Month"]]` on the example you have in the question I get the required result. I'm using pandas `1.3.1`

Comment: The data frame that I posted is a sample of my data. The code you shared with me works on that one. The code does NOT work on my actual data frame. It's weird.

Comment: I ended up doing this:
df['Month'] = df['load_date'].dt.strftime("%m")

Now, I can get all the records that have 01 for Month. Done. Thanks for the assist.